# How to increase document list performance on client's computer?

Tags: document-library, performance

I am working on a new SPS 2010 installation for a client that will be used to replace their intranet.  As it stands, the current intranet contains around 1000 documents that are saved amongst various network drives.  Part of the client's requirement for the new site is that they want all of these documents in one list so that they can update the metadata and view the site contents from one central location.  The issue that I am running into now is that displaying all of these documents as one list causes document list page to slow way down which makes the editing of the document meta data a slow process.

My questions is if there is anything that can be done from either the server, the list, or on the client's computer to try and speed up the performance of the document list page without having to use directories.  The installation is running on one server that contains both SPS2010 and SQL2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "list", are you referring to a document library? If so, you can set the pagination for the views to only return maybe 100 items at a time, which should pose no real performance issues.

Any slowness in drawing the the list would be down the client PC in most cases, as longer lists mean the browser has to render many more KB of markup.

If this is not the case, then is there a delay before the page is delivered to the user, or does the client browser "lock up" as the page is coming down?

Comment: Yes, I do mean library, sorry for the confusion.  The page loads fine, it's the actual selection of the documents takes a few seconds to register and is sluggish overall.

I was hoping to find a solution without having to use pagination, but if it comes down to it, I'll have to go that route.

Comment: For bulk editing of the document metadata, have you tried the "Edit in Datasheet" view?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with James about paging.  But since it isn't an option, perhaps you could create custom views with filters so that you are only showing a subset of the data.  Probably rarely will anyone actually want to scroll through an entire doc lib of 1,000 docs.

Another thing that may be helpful would be to create index columns in the library settings.  Choose the columns that are used as sorts and filters.  Although I agree with James that in this case the server isn't going to be the biggest bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you like to check out this KB just to dopuble check it is not a browser issue:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2270545

Bye Marco